# Rails 6 how to decorate application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, draper

I've got an `application.html.erb` where I want move calculation of unread user messages into some decorator/helper, basically because it looks like this:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to 'Messages', conversations_path %>
  <% counter = @conversations.map do |conversation| %>
    <% unless conversation.unread_message_count(current_user).zero? %>
      <% conversation.unread_message_count(current_user) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
(<%= counter.sum %>)
```

I know the basic concept of decorators but I'm wondering if I have `ConversationDecorator` in `app/decorators/conversation_decorator.rb` with defined `counter` method with @conversations.map block there, how to use this decorator inside of `application.html.erb` ?

Example ConversationDecorator:

```
class ConversationDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  def unread_counter
    @conversations.map do |conversation|
      conversation.unread_message_count(current_user) unless conversation.unread_message_count(current_user).zero?
    end.sum
  end
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with a regular view helper? What's `ApplicationDecorator`? Are you using Draper?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, I'm using Draper to decorate ActiveAdmin views

Comment: It *looks* like you're trying to decorate the "conversations" collection, so you'd want a [collection decorator](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#user-content-decorating-the-collection-itself) but thinking of it as a helper. An `ApplicationDecorator` is meant to be something that *all* decorators inherit from, which it doesn't seem like this is. I might take a step back and read through the Draper docs on GH.

Comment: Couldn't I use a separate decorator that is independent of the Drapper? or maybe just `::CounterHelper.unread_counter` (inside app/helpers/counter_helper.rb) with map block there? but I don't know if this is the way to call helpers inside the view, I'm totally junior in Rails views.

Comment: https://www.rubyguides.com/2020/01/rails-helpers/ etc; it's generally a good idea to seek out help via tutorials/docs/etc. first, then ask specific questions once there's code involved.

Comment: I would start by addressing the pretty obvious n+1 query issue posed by `conversation.unread_message_count(current_user)` before you get busy decorating.  Especially if this is going to be happening on every page load. You probally want something like `@conversations = Conversation.select('conversations.*', 'COUNT(messages.*) AS unread_message_count').joins(:user, :messages).where(users: { id: current_user.id }, messages: { status: :unread }).group(:id)`

Comment: Thats a really simplefied example as if its a multi-user chat you would have a join table to keep track which users have read which messages. But you get the point - select an aggregate when fetching the conversations instead of doing n+1 queries per row to fetch the count. Also generating the sum is NOT the job of the view or a decorator. It should either be generated from the controller or a model method if doing another query is acceptable.